# Struggling with making an audience/public for an gladiator arena

Tags: objects, performance, instances

I am a blender newbie, slowly catching up with the program and geting into 3D modeling. I've managed to create a huge arena model, and I have a lot of audience seats that should eventually be filled with people... I just can't think of how could I fill the entire arena with people, without making it way to big of a performance struggle... Does anyone have any idea how that is usually done? Like just a guideline in which direction should I head with it?

EDIT: I want to use the scene for gaming purposes (fighters inside of the arena) in Unreal Engine 4. Since it is a top-down level in UE4, I will need the crowd in the audience. Also I need to show the entire arena with crowd for the intro animation in the level. So am wondering how to simulate, let's say 5000 people in a crowd, cheering ? (like they do in the Football games, for instance)

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check out the Crowd Master add-on. http://crowdmaster.org/

Comment: Could you better describe your siutuation? Why in your opinion are you struggling with performance? Are you referring to the modeling in the 3D viewport or render times? What's the purpose of thes scene? Are you using this in a game engine or a shot? Does it requires to handle several LODs because you need close up of the crowd or it's always in the background?

Comment: I edited the post to answer your sub-questions. I was wondering if having 2000+ low poly people in a stadium, cheering in a simple animation, would be too much for a level performance-wise